# Number of paths

Tags: combinatorics

Let $k,n$ and $m$ - positive integers, such that $|n-m|<k$. Grasshopper wants to get from point $(0;0)$ to point (m,n). Grasshopper moves jumps. Jump up or $+1$, or $1$ right. Find the number of ridge paths that do not have common points with lines $y=x+k$ and $y=x-k$.

**My work so far:**
[image]
For the rectangle, but not limited to lines: $$N=\frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!}$$

If $k = 2$, the number of ways of $2^{\min \left\{m, n\right\}}$. If $k = 3$, then we have  $f(m, n)\cdot 3^{\min \left\{m, n\right\} - 1}$, where $f (m, n) = 2$ if $m = n$, and $f (m, n) = 3$, if $m \not= n$. Not the fact that it is so -  derived formula is not proved. And when $k\ge 4$ no general laws can not see.

Comment: Can you explain the formulas you have for $k = 2$ and $k = 3$? I do not understand how they work/how they satisfy the statement.